# Testing if ngModel and formControl changes are synchronised with view

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-test

I'm currently working on unit tests for a couple of components which implement `ControlValueAccessor` and I'm unable to test if the programatic changes passed to `formControl` are synchronised in view respectively. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing or is it caused by something else (like component logic itself)? Using jest for tests. Thank you in advance.

Component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'some-selector',
    styleUrls: ['some.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ClientVerificationNoteFormComponent),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `
        <input #inputElRef [(ngModel)]="input" (ngModelChange)="onChange(inputElRef.value)">
    `,
})
export class SomeComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    input = '';
    onTouched: () => void = () => ({});
    onChange: (value: string) => void = () => ({});

    writeValue(input: string): void {
        this.input = input;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (v: string) => void): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the following test doesn't work (I also tried calling the `detectChanges`, `tick`, and `detectChanges` again, but it wouldn't work anyways):

```js
@Component({ template: '<some-selector [formControl]="control"></some-selector>' })
class TestingView {
    control = new FormControl('default');
}

// ...basic test setup with TestBed...
it('should set synchronise formControl\'s value with view', () => {
    component.control.setValue('someValue');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const inputRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    expect(inputRef.nativeElement.value).toBe('someValue'); // <-- FAILS with actual: 'default' / expected: 'someValue'
});
```

I realised, that the following also doesn't work (this test runs on the component itself, without a host):

```js
it('should synchronise ngModel\'s change with view', () => {
    component.input = 'someValue';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const inputRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    expect(inputRef.nativeElement.value).toBe('someValue'); // <-- FAILS with actual: '' / expected: 'someValue'
});
```

Comment: Maybe this question will help you get what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829271/testing-two-way-binding-in-angular-with-jest. It is only for ngModel, however his approach is slightly more complex than yours by using events to change the value of a specific field. Anyway, worth a try :)

Comment: @mikegross Thank you, but what the user there is asking is actually the other side of synchronisation... basically if view changes update the model respectively.

Comment: Don't you have to `fixture.detectChange()`  BEFORE making an actual change?